# Magento 2.4 "Incorrect theme identification key" issue while creating Custom cron

Tags: magento2

I am getting "Incorrect theme identification key" while creating custom cron job. Magento version is 2.4.2.

[image]

Error in log file:

> [2021-06-18 00:50:38] main.INFO: Cron Job update_qty_leatherhides is run [] []
> [2021-06-18 00:50:38] main.ERROR: Cron Job update_qty_leatherhides has an error: Incorrect theme identification key. Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":208142336,"emalloc_start":197509928} [] []
> [2021-06-18 00:50:38] main.CRITICAL: Incorrect theme identification key {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Incorrect theme identification key at /chroot/home/a5ad8123/0e80a7b082.nxcli.net/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/FlyweightFactory.php:62)"} []

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Magento classes used to define crons, should not be extended from any other class such as `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into theme `VALUES (4, 1, 'Magento/luma', 'Magento Luma Cron', NULL, 0, 'crontab', 0, 'Magento/luma');`

Answer (score 0):

I too came across this issue but the description of the error isn't entirely helpful. I had these errors in my cron_schedule table for cron jobs I had built into a controller class. Looks like Magento 2.4.2 doesn't like you doing that so I moved the code to be in its own class (not extending from anything) and voila errors gone.